# Create new pdf in loop with iText Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I want to create a new pdf for each iteration of the loop so i wrote the below code in java:

```
PdfWriter writer;
PdfDocument pdf;
Document document;

int i=0;
while(condition){
    writer = new PdfWriter("test_"+Integer.toString(i)+".pdf");
    pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    document = new Document(pdf);

    //content code here

    document.close()
    i++;
}
```

i get the below exception on the line of the `document.close()` command:

> Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Pdf
>   indirect object belongs to other PDF document. Copy object to current
>   pdf document.     at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:184)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:174)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:104)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:176)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:104)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:176)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.write(PdfOutputStream.java:104)
>     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.writeToBody(PdfWriter.java:335)
>     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.flushObject(PdfWriter.java:243)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.flushObject(PdfDocument.java:1446)
>     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:155)  at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.flush(PdfObject.java:128)   at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObjectWrapper.flush(PdfObjectWrapper.java:96)
>     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:489)  at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.flush(PdfPage.java:448)   at
>   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:739)   at
>   com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:120)     at
>   gr.moh.Pdf.main(Pdf.java:224)

i have tried a lot but i cannot find why i get an error. If i do it without a loop it works. Any help?

P.S: i use itext 7

Comment: You appear to use some PDF objects in multiple runs of the loop in your `//content code here`, i.e. for multiple target PDFs. This can result in exceptions like yours.

Comment: thank you! i use a Style above the loop in order to assign fonts to paragraphs. I added them into the loop and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the below code out of the loop and it should be into the loop...

```
PdfFont normalFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+"\\arial.ttf", "Identity-H", true);
                normal.setFont(normalFont).setFontSize(14);

                Style red = new Style();
                PdfFont redFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+"\\arial.ttf", "Identity-H", true);
                red.setFont(redFont).setFontSize(14).setFontColor(Color.RED);

                Style big = new Style();
                PdfFont bigFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+"\\arial.ttf", "Identity-H", true);
                big.setFont(bigFont).setFontSize(18).setBold();
```